# sbt multi-module project: inter-dependency of integration tests

Tags: scala, sbt, multi-module

I have a multi-module sbt project with integration tests for each module. Module `a` depends on module `b` for compile, test, and integration test scope. So I have it setup like this in a Build.scala:

```
lazy val authorizationdeciderservice = Project(
  id = "a",
  base = file("modules/a"),
  configurations = Seq(IntegrationTest),
  dependencies = Seq(b % "compile;it->test;it")
)
```

Now the `compile` and `it->test` dependency work fine, but the `it` dependecy does not, in that I am unable to access resources on the `it` path in `b` from integration tests in `a`.

What might the issue be?

Comment: I'm having the same problem :\

Answer (score 2):

`b % "compile;it->test;it"` is the same as `b % "compile->compile;it->test;it->compile"`. To access resources on the it path in b from integration tests in a, there should be `"it->it"`.

Comment: This is not working for me in sbt 1.8.0.

Comment: Those are q/a of the pre-1.x era

Answer (score 0):

Using `"it->it"` wasn't working for me in sbt 1.8.0. I was able to make it work with `"test->it"`. This has the downside of making `"b"`'s integration test code available in `"a"`'s regular tests, but it at least avoids the code duplication I would have done. Eventually I'll move to the recommended separate sub-project for integration tests, per sbt 1.9.0's [release notes](https://eed3si9n.com/sbt-1.9.0-beta#IntegrationTest).